# ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer; ubuntu in Docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to setup some Ubuntu images in Docker, to be used as honeypots.

I've followed a guide from here:
https://github.com/mrschyte/dockerpot

This is a copy of the Docker file i use:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:screencast' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin prohibit-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# SSH login fix. Otherwise user is kicked off after login
RUN sed 's@session\s*required\s*pam_loginuid.so@session optional pam_loginuid.so@g' -i /etc/pam.d/sshd

ENV NOTVISIBLE "in users profile"
RUN echo "export VISIBLE=now" >> /etc/profile

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

Running `docker ps` I can see that the contrainers are created:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b7c1962cfc27        def9be976ec5        "/sbin/init"        45 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       22/tcp              honeypot-192.168.122.1
```

but when I try to connect to them from my machine, the connection is reset with the error: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `/sbin/init` from the init script, fixed the issue.

Something about this should not be used in docker as it may not initialize the services.

Comment: I think this line CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"] not required on Dockerfile, right?

Comment: It works fine with it, but not sure if it is required. Dont want to rebuild the image, now that it seems to be working.

Comment: How you remove /sbin/init from the init script?

Comment: The script is from https://github.com/mrschyte/dockerpot project, under scripts. Per the guide its placed in `/usr/bin/honeypot`. The script has on line 17, where it runs the docker container, last part of it has the `sbin/init` in it.